# How to dynamically create array to update ZingChart treemap

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, zingchart

I am trying to dynamically create this data array for ZingCharts and am stumped.

Basically, I need to make this structure:

```
var series = [{
  text: "Democratic", 
  style: {
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    },

  children: [{ 
    text: "California",
    value: 55,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    },

  }, {
    text: "Oregon",
    value: 7,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    },
  }]
}, 
{
  text: "Republican", 
  style: {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    },
  children: [{ 
    text: "Texas",
    value: 38,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    },
  }, {
    text: "Georgia",
    value: 16,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    },
  }]
}, {
  text: "TossUp", 
  style: {
      backgroundColor: "grey"
    },
  children: [{ 
    text: "Arizona",
    value: 22,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "grey"
    },
  }]
}, ]
}]
};
```

I don't know what the correct way of doing this is. I am tempted to do something like this:

```
result.push("text: '" + data[0].party + "'")
```

I need to do this with all 50 states, and the data is coming in a structure like this:

```
var data = [{
  "color": "blue",
  "party": "Democratic",
  "text": "California",
  "value": 55,
}, {
  "color": "blue",
  "party": "Democratic",
  "text": "Oregon",
  "value": 7,
}, {
  "color": "red",
  "party": "Republican",
  "text": "Texas",
  "value": 38,
}, {
  "color": "red",
  "party": "Republican",
  "text": "Georgia",
  "value": 16,
}, {
  "color": "grey",
  "party": "Democratic",
  "text": "Arizona",
  "value": 11,
}];
```

Any tips on what I should be searching for would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reduce` function and a `hash table` to create the data structure that you desire:

```js
var data=[{color:"blue",party:"Democratic",text:"California",value:55},{color:"blue",party:"Democratic",text:"Oregon",value:7},{color:"red",party:"Republican",text:"Texas",value:38},{color:"red",party:"Republican",text:"Georgia",value:16},{color:"grey",party:"Democratic",text:"Arizona",value:11}];

var result = data.reduce(function(hash) {
  return function(prev, curr) {
    if (hash[curr.color]) {
      hash[curr.color].children.push({
        text: curr.text,
        value: curr.value,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        }
      });
    } else {
      hash[curr.color] = {};
      hash[curr.color].children = hash[curr.color].children || [];
      prev.push({
        text: curr.party,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        },
        children: hash[curr.color].children
      });
      hash[curr.color].children.push({
        text: curr.text,
        value: curr.value,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        }
      });
    }
    return prev;
  };
}(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top: 0;max-height: 100%!important;}
```

Let me know your thoughts on this, thanks!

Comment: Very clean! Thanks for answering

Comment: @kukkuz - this was a great help. I am actually trying to figure something out related to this if you care to take a look. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368831/fine-tuning-hash-to-dynamically-create-zingcharts-treemap-array