# Fine tuning hash to dynamically create ZingCharts treemap array

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, hashmap, zingchart

**First**: Thanks for reading, but there is a lot in this, it may be easier to see it in the CodePen examples that are linked at the bottom.

I recently asked a question about how to dynamically create an array for a treemap, and was pointed in the right direction. I have been able to do some simple manipulation to the hash table, but can't figure out how to do the final step.

Currently the treemap has 2 "levels", that was done like this:

```
var data=[{color:"blue",party:"Democratic",text:"California",value:55},{color:"blue",party:"Democratic",text:"Oregon",value:7},{color:"red",party:"Republican",text:"Texas",value:38},{color:"red",party:"Republican",text:"Georgia",value:16},{color:"grey",party:"Democratic",text:"Arizona",value:11}];

var result = data.reduce(function(hash) {
  return function(prev, curr) {
    if (hash[curr.color]) {
      hash[curr.color].children.push({
        text: curr.text,
        value: curr.value,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        }
      });
    } else {
      hash[curr.color] = {};
      hash[curr.color].children = hash[curr.color].children || [];
      prev.push({
        text: curr.party,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        },
        children: hash[curr.color].children
      });
      hash[curr.color].children.push({
        text: curr.text,
        value: curr.value,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        }
      });
    }
    return prev;
  };
}(Object.create(null)), []);
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is bring an additional criteria and add another level. For example, under "Republican" and "Democratic" you'd have subcategories for "Likely", "Leaning", and "Tipping" but for "Toss Up" you wouldn't have any of those.

Here is the end result that I'm trying to make:

```
  series: [{
      text: "Democratic", 
      style: { "backgroundColor": "blue" },
      children: [{ 
        text: "Likely",
        style: { "backgroundColor": "darkblue" },
        children: [{
          text: "Alabama",
          value: 8,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "darkblue" },
        }, {
          text: "New Mexico",
          value: 14,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "darkblue" },
        }]
      }, {
        text: "Leaning",
        style: { "backgroundColor": "blue" },
        children: [{
          text: "Florida",
          value: 9,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "blue" },
        }, {
          text: "North Carolina",
          value: 6,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "blue" },
        }]
      }, {
        text: "Tipping",
        style: { "backgroundColor": "lightblue" },
        children: [{
          text: "Utah",
          value: 4,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "lightblue" },
        }, {
          text: "Idaho",
          value: 5,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "lightblue" },
        }]
      }]
    },

    { text: "Republican",
      style: { "backgroundColor": "red" },
      children: [{
        text: "Likely",
        style: { "backgroundColor": "darkred" },
        children: [{
          text: "alabama",
          value: 13,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "darkred" },
        }, {
          text: "New Mexico",
          value: 14,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "darkred" },
        }]
      }, {
        text: "Leaning",
        style: { "backgroundColor": "red" },
        children: [{
          text: "Florida",
          value: 9,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "red" },
        }, {
          text: "North Carolina",
          value: 6,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "red" },
        }]
      }, {
        text: "Tipping",
        style: { "backgroundColor": "lightred" },
        children: [{
          text: "Utah",
          value: 27,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "lightred" },
        }, {
          text: "Idaho",
          value: 12,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "lightred" },
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      text: "Toss Up",
      style: { "backgroundColor": "grey" },
      children: [{
          text: "alabama",
          value: 10,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "grey" },
        }, {
          text: "New Mexico",
          value: 14,
          style: { "backgroundColor": "grey" },
      }]
    },
  ]
};
```

I have been trying to figure out how to modify the example I was given to do that, but have been failing for hours. I'm not sure what I should be looking up. I think in the Else statement inside the "prev.push" (line 2040 [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwXzVV)) is where the adjustment should be happening, but I don't know how to implement it, I also suspect I need to change the whole approach.

```
var result = data.reduce(function(hash) {
  return function(prev, curr) {
    if (hash[curr.party]) { 
      console.log("if: " + curr.party + " " + curr.category);
      hash[curr.party].children.push({ 
        text: curr.text,
        value: curr.value,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        }
      });
    }

    else { 
      console.log("else: " + curr.party + " " + curr.category);
      hash[curr.party] = {};
      hash[curr.party].children = hash[curr.party].children || [];

      hash[curr.party].children.push({
        text: curr.text,
        value: curr.value,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        }
      });

      prev.push({
        text: curr.party,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        },
        children: hash[curr.party].children // children: [{ text: curr.category, children: [{ }] }]
      });

      hash[curr.category] = {};
      hash[curr.category].children = hash[curr.category].children || [];
      console.log("category");
      prev.push({
        text: curr.category,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        },
        children: hash[curr.category].children
      });
    }
    return prev;
  };
}(Object.create(null)), []);
```

To wrap up:

1. Here is a [CodePen of the basic structure of the goal](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEvMwz)
2. Here is my [current code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwXzVV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier the classification was being done based on `color`, seeing your data I guess we can do it based on `party` now. As there is another level added to the tree, we can classify that based on `category`.

So there are many changes - see demo below:

```js
var data = [{"text":"California","value":55,"color":"#000066","party":"Democratic","compare":1,"category":"Likely"},{"text":"Connecticut","value":7,"color":"#000066","party":"Democratic","compare":1,"category":"Likely"},{"text":"Colorado","value":9,"color":"#3333CC","party":"Democratic","compare":2,"category":"Leaning"},{"text":"Florida","value":29,"color":"#9999FF","party":"Democratic","compare":3,"category":"Tipping"},{"text":"Iowa","value":6,"color":"red","party":"Republican","compare":4,"category":"Likely"},{"text":"Alabama","value":9,"color":"#CC3333","party":"Republican","compare":5,"category":"Leaning"},{"text":"Alaska","value":3,"color":"#FF9999","party":"Republican","compare":6,"category":"Tipping"},{"text":"Arizona","value":11,"color":"#666666","party":"Toss-Up","compare":7,"category":"Toss Up"},{"text":"Texas","value":11,"color":"#666666","party":"Toss-Up","compare":7,"category":"Toss Up"}];

var result = data.reduce(function(hash) {
  return function(prev, curr) {
    if (!hash[curr.party]) {
      hash[curr.party] = {};
      hash[curr.party].children = hash[curr.party].children || [];
      prev.push({
        text: curr.party,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        },
        children: hash[curr.party].children
      });
    } else if (hash[curr.party] && hash[curr.party][curr.category]) {
      hash[curr.party][curr.category].children.push({
        text: curr.text,
        value: curr.value,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: curr.color
        }
      });
    }

    if (hash[curr.party] && !hash[curr.party][curr.category]) {
      if (curr.category == "Toss Up") {
        hash[curr.party].children.push({
          text: curr.text,
          value: curr.value,
          style: {
            backgroundColor: curr.color
          }
        });
      } else {
        hash[curr.party][curr.category] = {};
        hash[curr.party][curr.category].children = hash[curr.party][curr.category].children || [];
        hash[curr.party].children.push({
          text: curr.category,
          style: {
            backgroundColor: curr.color
          },
          children: hash[curr.party][curr.category].children
        });
        hash[curr.party][curr.category].children.push({
          text: curr.text,
          value: curr.value,
          style: {
            backgroundColor: curr.color
          }
        });
      }
    }
    return prev;
  };
}(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {top: 0;max-height: 100%!important;}
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate you helping me twice, I was just taking another stab at this after getting home, I am going to try this out and will let you know!

Comment: Ok, so this is all working perfect with my full test data except for with the "Toss Up". The issue is that "Toss Up" never has the Likely/Leaning/Tipping children in it. You can see in this pic that right now it still does a second level of "Toss Up" (http://i.imgur.com/dUJRKM7.png). Also, I put this new CodePen together with my full test data so you can see it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jMgoJa?editors=0010 Thanks again!

Comment: @NealJones added a condition for removing the extra level for `Toss up`... let me know if that solves it, thanks!